# Subscripted value nor array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

This is my program to convert a binary to a decimal value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void con(){

    unsigned long long int dec = 0, bin;
    int i;

    printf ("\n Binary : ");
    scanf("%lld",&bin);



    for (i = strlen(bin) - 1; i <= 0; --i){    // Warning in here

       dec = dec + (bin[i] * pow (2, i));   // Error in here

    }

    printf(" Decimal : %lld",dec);

    con();

}

int main(){

    con();
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile the code, this error shows up ," Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". And this warning also ," Passing argument 1 of strlen makes pointer from integer without a cast".

Why am i getting these and how can i fix them?

Comment: `bin` is `unsigned long long int`, not a pointer or an array...

Comment: @StoryTeller So i should use it as an array ?

Comment: You should declare it as an array, if you intend to use it as one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

Most important is the variable `bin`. You probably want it to be a string like "1001001001" but you define it as `unsigned long long int`. Instead you should do:

```
char bin[100];
scanf("%s", bin);   // Note: Not recommended! Use fgets instead.
```

Here `scanf` is not recommended as the user may overflow your buffer. Please use `fgets` instead.

As suggested by @MayurK: If you want to use `scanf` then at least do:

```
scanf("%99s", bin);
```

to prevent buffer from overflow.

Then this part:

```
dec = dec + (bin[i] * pow (2, i));
```

is wrong as bin[i] is not a number but a char.

You could do:

```
dec = 2 * dec + (bin[i] - '0');  // Note: No error checks which is bad
```

It will work as long as the user only inputs `0` and `1`. In real code you should check that the user actually did so.

Finally you should not call `con` at the end of the function as it will give an endless loop. So delete that call:

```
    printf(" Decimal : %lld",dec);

    // DELETE THIS con();

}
```

Comment: Better scanf("%99s", bin);.

Comment: @MayurK - Thanks - good point. For a moment I forgot that possibility as I always use `fgets` instead. Answer updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
dec = dec + (bin[i] * pow (2, i));  //bin is a numeric type
```

In this line you are trying to use a variable of *unsigned long long* type as array. Every numeric type is taken as a full value, you can't use array indexing to access separate digits. If you want to use it as a array use a char* or character array.

And you are also passing a *unsigned long long* to strlen(const char * str) function.